# Illustrator Actions are corrupted when reloading document

Tags: adobe-illustrator, actions

I have a simple action I have created to do orthographic SSR projections. However, when I close and open Illustrator, the parameters for each operation are reset to defaults. What might be causing this?

I am using Illustrator CC (23) on Windows 10. I assume it might have something to do with being on a corporate computer that is heavily locked down.

I also get

> the object XXXX is not available

error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your profile files are on a network drive then adobe's software sometimes bug out because your disk access is too slow. There is no support for this, no solution, even adobe admits this. Other than putting your profile on a local machine or upgrading your network disks, which is most likely beyond your means.. You can reload the actions after the software has been opened.

Comment: They are local, but there's a handful of virus scan/backup/anti-exfiltration software that probably do lock the files at inopportune times

Comment: Open the .aia file in a text editor. Does the file show the expected values, or just default ones? The problem may be a matter of administrative privileges. Try opening Illustrator with "run as administrator" and save the actions then.

Comment: I have some Actions with Scale panel and all are working fine. Try to save and reload the actions. Otherwise... that could be a bug.

Comment: I do not have admin privileges and they require a good degree of social engineering to get them. I'll see if admin privileges solves it next time I am working on this type of task.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the transform tools use the **Transform Panel** to record the action. You can put percentage numbers at the width and height field.

[image: Transfrom panel]

Comment: I tried it and it also suffers from not saving the action. What was your thinking that this would change? Further - the transform panel does not save percentages - just absolute numbers.